# ¿Hay equivalente en el castellano a "desaplaudido" del portugués brasileño?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, coloquialismos

Leo [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/TCAvendano/status/1004704217012072449):

> En portugués brasileño existe una palabra para esa gente que siempre intenta llamar la atención pero que no lo logra porque en realidad no destaca en nada: “Es un desaplaudido”. Es maravillosa. Tenemos que importarla al castellano.

La verdad es que me ha gustado mucho el concepto, pero [WordReference no lo recoge](http://www.wordreference.com/ptes/desaplaudido) y distintas personas responden al autor diciendo que no lo conocen. Será, pues, algo bastante nuevo y coloquial.

¿Qué se nos ocurre como traducción al castellano? Sería algo así como una mezcla entre [*mequetrefe*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OxuqCFI) (poca cosa) y [*pimpín*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T1W2jin) (acepción no recogida en el DLE consistente en tener ínfulas de mucho, sin serlo).

Comment: En Chile el **pintamonos** fue hace 20 o 30 años el don nadie que vivía haciendo tonteras para llamar la atención. Ahora la palabra ya no es realmente negativa, cualquier persona puede _pintamonear_ en una fiesta. No es lo mismo que el [pintamonas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T4mb8Ox) del DRAE, que acá no se usa.

Comment: El campo es amplísimo. En Twitter Argentina se está usando otorgale el "Premio Guiensó" (< *quién sos*) a gente que hace declaraciones altisonantes o se coloca como referente de algo sin ser importante ni autoridad en el tema. Viene [con gesto](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/950241842783772672/6NILgsOy_400x400.jpg) y todo.

Comment: Interesante pregunta.  Me hace pensar en los *wannabes* de inglés (viene de *want to be [like]*).  Me pregunto si se podría importar *desaplaudido* así como así al español.

Comment: @JuanJimenez interesante! En España _lúcido_ no se usa en este sentido. Te animo a publicarlo como respuesta, pues al fin damos con un término equivalente que en algún lugar de habla hispana se usa.

Comment: @walen sí, me di cuenta al editar la respuesta. Inicialmente la imaginé esdrújula, pero luego pensándolo me di cuenta que aguda tenía más sentido para este contexto

Comment: Otro comentario sobre la pregunta... el portugués brasileño es un desafío para traducir porque la jerga local y regional (por estados) tiende a evolucionar mucho más rápido que en otros países. En Puerto Rico ocurre lo mismo, pero en muchos casos es porque se está reciclando alguna expresión de una generación anterior que había perdido aceptación, o porque algo en las noticias (generalmente de EEUU y en muchos casos de la farándula) causa que se cree una expresión nueva. Mi teoría es que mientras más humorosa y expresiva la cultura, más ocurre esto.

Answer (score 1):

En Puerto Rico sería un **lucido**, alguien que se trata de lucir o lucirse como lo que no es, o que trata de hacerse el centro de atención cuando no debe.

Ejemplo:

> Tú siempre te haces el **lucido** cuando vienen tus amigos a visitar.